# Add CSS based on window height

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pop up window that looks great as long as the viewer is using a large screen (over 750px high). I'd like to add a CSS selector to push up the important content (and obscure the title and intro info which is expendable) for people viewing on laptops. I thought the easiest way would be to raise the body tag up -180 px.

I thought it would be a good job for my first shot at jQuery but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried:

```
if($(window).height() <= 650)
   $(body).css("margin-top","-180px");
```

and also

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).height() < 670) {
        $("body").css('margin-top', '-180px');
    }
    else {
        $("body").css('margin-top', '0px');
    }
});​
```

but neither seems to work.  How can I change the body styling based on the current window height?

Comment: You should use media queries

Comment: You can't set the margin-top to "-180px" as far as I know... you have to get the current height, subtract 180 from it, then pass it back in.  But I agree that media queries are probably the way to go (Skeleton CSS might be a good resource to check out).

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YhZG4/

Comment: Oh my bad I misread... I thought he wanted to set the margin to 180 from what it was before.  Doh.

Answer (score 3):

Just use media queries to serve up differing versions or styles:

```
@media only screen 
and (max-height: 650px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```